# Programming Arduino Mega using joystick to control DC motor

Tags: arduino, joystick

I am trying to control a DC Motor using a joystick with an Arduino Mega. I have been able to run the DC motor, as well as finding the potentiometer values of the joystick separately. I am using just the y-axis of the joystick in order to have the motor move forward when the joytick is up, then backwards when the joystick is down. The middle of the joystick is ~504.

```
// motor one
int enA = 3;
int in1 = 22;
int in2 = 24;
// y_joystick
int y_joy = A1;
int joy_value = 0;
void setup() {
  // set all the motor control pins to outputs
  pinMode(enA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (y_joy, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  joy_value = analogRead(y_joy);
  if (0 < joy_value < 500) {
    digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(in2, HIGH);
    analogWrite(enA, 120);
  } else if (511 < joy_value < 1024) {
    digitalWrite(in1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
    analogWrite(enA, 120);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
    analogWrite(enA, 0);
  }
  Serial.print("y-axis: ");
  Serial.println(analogRead(y_joy));
  Serial.print("\n");
  delay(1000);
}
```

Now this code prints out the joystick values in the serial monitor, but does not rotate the motor at all. I am positive that the connections are correct because they are the same connections I used before to just run the motor forward and back on its own. I am probably missing something in my code but just can't see it so any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: what is `enA` ? you said you have run the motor using arduino board. can you show that sketch too?

Comment: Shouldn't enA be `A3`, not (D)3?

Answer (score 1):

You should use logical operators with a double condition. Try to replace your if/else statement:

```
if (0 < joy_value < 500) {
    ...
} else if (511 < joy_value < 1024) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

by:

```
if (0 < joy_value && joy_value < 500) {
    ...
} else if (511 < joy_value && joy_value < 1024) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

Comment: @Wmson - also better use: `Serial.println(joy_value);`